# Ansible Making variables optional

Tags: python, variables, ansible, yaml

I do not arrive to use the argument omit with a task for create vswitch.

I have  error '__omit_place_holder_81417e0c9c0a92falf5ce7dccf224fa67be93fb4'

I do not understand the problem

Thanks for your help

```
- name: Add a VMware vSwitch with multiple NICs
  community.vmware.vmware_vswitch:
    hostname: "{{ hostname.1 }}"
    username: "{{ esxi_username }}"
    password: "{{ esxi_password }}"
    #esxi_hostname: "{{ hostname.1 }}"
    switch: "{{ item.name }}"
    nics: 
    - "{{ item.nic1| default(omit)}}"
    - "{{ item.nic2| default(omit)}}"
    mtu: "{{ item.mtu }}"
    number_of_ports: 2
    validate_certs: no
  delegate_to: localhost
  ignore_errors: yes
  loop:
    - "{{ net_vmk }}"
    - "{{ net_vm }}"
    - "{{ net_tech }}"
    - "{{ net_sto }}"
#conf esxi
hostname:
  1: lab-esxi
  2:
  3:
  4:
esxi_username: root
esxi_password: ...
#conf vswitch
net_vmk:
  name: vs-vmk
  nic2: vmnic4
  mtu: 1500
```

Documentation Ansible
[1]: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#making-variables-optional

Answer (score 0):

I found it :-)

```
- name: Add a VMware vSwitch with multiple NICs
  community.vmware.vmware_vswitch:
    hostname: "{{ hostname.1 }}"
    username: "{{ esxi_username }}"
    password: "{{ esxi_password }}"
    #esxi_hostname: "{{ hostname.1 }}"
    switch: "{{ item.name }}"
    nics: "{{ item.nic1|default(omit)}}"
    nics: "{{ item.nic2|default(omit)}}"
    mtu: "{{ item.mtu }}"
    number_of_ports: 2
    validate_certs: no
  delegate_to: localhost
  ignore_errors: yes
  loop:
    - "{{ net_vmk }}"
    - "{{ net_vm }}"
    - "{{ net_tech }}"
    - "{{ net_sto }}"
```